# How to PHP echo something when using JS's window.location?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

here is my problem.
I am making a webshop and for my alerts and notifications I use three types of `divs`  (they differ only in background-color) that disappear after 3-4 secs. The markup is basically the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class='alert-warning'>
   Email already in use!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert-warning{
   background-color: rgba(255,193,7,.75);
   border-radius: 30px;
   top: 10%;
   right: 10%;
   position: absolute;
   padding: 1em;
   font-size: 1em;
   color: #eee;
   z-index: 502;
}
```

Now, The problem that I have: When the user enters an email that's already used, my little alert div should appear in the upper right corner, just like it does when he tries to add to cart when he is not logged in.
[image: see the picture]

When the user enters an email that's already in use, I have the page redirect to show him again my register-box, that is in the url = `index.php?show=register` so I have that echoed. The problem is that if I echo my div before the redirection, it appears for a very short time then the page redirects, if I put it afterwards it never appears.

**PHP**

```
elseif($already_registered){
                    echo '<script>window.location="index.php?show=register"</script>';
                    ?>
                        <div class='animated fadeInUp alert-warning'>
                            This e-mail is already in use.
                        </div>
                    <?php

                }
```

I am a high school graduate and this is the first time I'm using `PHP` for projects of this size so I'm not that familiar with it yet. I hope my question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't redirect the user anywhere when he enters an email that's already in use, use AJAX or better yet, fetch, to get whether or not the email is already in use from the server. This can happen while the user is filling out the register form and therefore makes it easier to register for the user

Comment: Thank you but I do not want to dive into JAX yet. I know that for serious projects you have to use it but this is just a homework project and I wanted to make it look cool. I just don't understnad why my code doesn't work. Please provide an answer to that if you can.

Comment: You should specify what your ideal answer is. If you have a preference between displaying something before or after redirect, that's a detail you should put in your question so people answering know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a delay in the relocation.

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location="index.php?show=register"}, 5000)</script>
```

This way `window.location` will trigger after `5000` milliseconds (5 secs)

---

### Update

To display it after the redirection you will need to change you code to something like this:

```
elseif($already_registered){
  echo '<script>window.location="index.php?show=register&redirected=1"</script>';
}
```

Notice the `&redirected=1` part. This is to know we were redirected and must output the message

So now in your `index.php` file you will add

```
if(isset($_GET["redirected"])){
  <div class='animated fadeInUp alert-warning'>
      This e-mail is already in use.
  </div>
}
```

This way we confirm we were redirected and show the message

Comment: Thank you, that is one way of doing it :) But how could I display it after the redirection? I don't get it why my code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

When the script is evaluated, the user is taken to another page, so "echoing after" the redirect won't do anything for you.

If you're going to stick with this route, rather than use something like AJAX calls, I'd suggest adding a parameter to index.php (as you have for show) that lets you specify why they were redirected.

Something along the lines of index.php?show=register&emailUsed=true would be enough to let you know that you need to display the error along with the registration page, and something like index.php?show=register&error=emailUsed would be helpful if you have a number of conditions to triage.